# rank data in subsets

Tags: r, ranking, aggregation

I have a data asset where one "unique"ID corresponds to multiple cases, shown below. I am looking for a way to create a column ranking each ID by another column but keeping the rank unique for each ID.

```
ID    number     Rank(column I'm trying to add)      
1       55         3
1       40         2
1       35         1
2       42         2
2       35         1
3       16         1
3       17         2
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

In R, if your first two columns are in a data frame called `mydf`, you can do:

```
 mydf$rank=unlist(with(mydf,tapply(number,ID,rank)))
```

Comment: Yes, I was trying to use R and this solved the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

An alternative, when you need to group and/or rank by multiple variables, using `dplyr` is:

```
mydf %>% 
    arrange(rank_var1, rank_var2, rank_var3) %>%
    group_by(group_var1, group_var2, group_var3) %>% 
    mutate(rank = rank(rank_var1), rank_desc = rank(-rank_var2)) %>%
    ungroup()
```